# Freezes waiting process

Tags: c#

I write code, which call powershell script to execute. The problem is that on Windows 7, all works perfectly. But in the Windows 8.1 one start of the five are freezes. So this is my code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();            
startInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = PathUnistallScript;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();//here code is freezes
```

At the moment I put a crutch, but I think this is a temporary solution.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
Thread.Sleep(5000);//wait the approximate number of seconds to complete the script 
process.Kill();
```

How do I write the code, that it does not freezes in Windows 8.1?

Comment: Take a look at `Process.Exited` event. Also don't use `Thread.Sleep` for waiting for a process. Use `Process.WaitForExit();`

Comment: There should be a simple open-source project that designed a class that would make this kind of thing easier than dealing with the raw Process class, there's plenty of questions here on SO that have gotten off to a bad start because everybody is forced to invent the wheel themselves.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen [This](https://github.com/jamesmanning/RunProcessAsTask) could be a start :)

Comment: Looks very promising. For my own needs I would need to have interactive access to the standard input for command line processes to feed them data as they run, but this looks like it could solve most peoples problems with Process.

Comment: @user3231442 What are you actually trying to do? do you just want to wait until the script finishes? or do you explictly need to kill the powershell after a certain amount of time?

Comment: Yuval Itzchakov. I need start powershell file, wait of his end, and read all result line to log file.